# Why binlog capture only postions

Tags: mysql, binlog

Please help me out, why master server records only position not statement.

```
### INSERT INTO `sanma`.`response`
### SET
###   @1=743096223
###   @2=0
###   @3='IR'
###   @4='UnderProcess'
###   @5=2015-05-29 20:51:34
###   @6=743053329
###   @7=NULL
###   @8=NULL
###   @9='758484829'
###   @10=1432912893
###   @11=758484829
###   @12='UnderProcess'
###   @13=0
###   @14=NULL
###   @15=NULL
###   @16=NULL
###   @17=NULL
# at 20535714
#150529 20:51:33 server id 71  end_log_pos 20535741     Xid = 84151212
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 20535741
#150529 20:44:01 server id 100  end_log_pos 20535779    GTID 0-100-3874997400
/*!100001 SET @@session.server_id=100*//*!*/;
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=3874997400*//*!*/;
BEGIN
/*!*/;
# at 20535779
# at 20535837
# at 20536877
# at 20537901
# at 20538944
# at 20539978
# at 20541012
# at 20542040
# at 20543076
# at 20544094
```

.
.
.
.
.

.
.
and sql_thread stuck on slave.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;` (on slave) and `SHOW MASTER STATUS;` (on master).

Answer (score 1):

Your MySQL Instance is using [binlog_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) as `ROW` and not `STATEMENT`.

You can check with one of the following:

```
SELECT @global.binlog_format;
#
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';
#
SELECT variable_value FROM information_schema.global variables
WHERE variable_name = 'binlgo_format';
```

This should be OK for you because it keeps the table layout a secret, known only to your developers, DBAs, and Project Managers. You will now be able to see the SQL with your current binary logs. I just mentioned this about 3 weeks ago : [Show sql statements from mysql binlog (GTID)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101651/show-sql-statements-from-mysql-binlog-gtid/101653#101653)

You could switch [binlog_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_binlog-format) to `MIXED` and see if it exposes the actual SQL.