# How can I parse mysql bin log file for statements (Row/Mixed Format)

Tags: mysql, binlog, mysqlbinlog

I have a mysql database running with binary log enabled. Unfortunately, a statement was executed by the client, which turned out erroneous. Since a number of records have been "affected", I want to begin by parsing the bin-log for data-changing statements from that time period. Then we might be able to begin picking up the pieces.

I have used:

```
mysqlbinlog -v --base64-output=decode-rows --start-datetime="2015-06-26 08:30:00" --stop-datetime="2015-06-26 09:30:00" data/mysql-bin.000005 > C:\temp\binlog.txt
```

The output is quite intimidating. What I would appreciate is a strategy for parsing out any INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements. Keep in mind I'm on MIXED MODE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you have `binlog_format=MIXED` some statements will appear as actual SQL. Other statements may get obfuscated like this:

```
### INSERT INTO `sanma`.`response`
### SET
###   @1=743096223
###   @2=0
###   @3='IR'
###   @4='UnderProcess'
###   @5=2015-05-29 20:51:34
###   @6=743053329
###   @7=NULL
###   @8=NULL
###   @9='758484829'
###   @10=1432912893
###   @11=758484829
###   @12='UnderProcess'
###   @13=0
###   @14=NULL
###   @15=NULL
###   @16=NULL
###   @17=NULL
# at 20535714
#150529 20:51:33 server id 71  end_log_pos 20535741     Xid = 84151212
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

That statement was possible to see because the `INSERT ... SET` syntax was used.

Other statements may get obfuscated beyond recognition. This is the risk of using MIXED or ROW.

I have dealt with this recently

- `Jun 02, 2015` : [Why binlog capture only postions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/103062/why-binlog-capture-only-postions/103086#103086)
- `May 15, 2015` : [Show sql statements from mysql binlog (GTID)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/101651/show-sql-statements-from-mysql-binlog-gtid/101653#101653)

The only thing you can do is

```
# Look for INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statements
mysqlbinlog ... > statements.sql
grep -i "^[IUD][NPE][SDL][EA][RT][TE]"     statements.sql  > dml.sql
grep -i "^### [IUD][NPE][SDL][EA][RT][TE]" statements.sql >> dml.sql
```

There are no guarantees you will catch every change in statement form when mysqld switches to binlog_format ROW intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

please use this tool for parsing the SQL statement

https://github.com/danfengcao/binlog2sql